# How to display the results in table,based on array

Tags: php, php-7.1

Here i have an array, i want to display array values in table format, i am new to PHP 7.1, if anyone knows means - update my answer, i tried but i am not able to get the answer

> print_r($companyResponse);

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [message] => Total 3 record(s) found.
    [total_record] => 3
    [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [companyId] => 3
                [companyName] => TCS
                [noOfDivision] => 7
                [companyAddress] => JP nagar
                [companyStatus] => 0
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [companyId] => 2
                [companyName] => IBM
                [noOfDivision] => 5
                [companyAddress] => Domlur
                [companyStatus] => 0
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [companyId] => 1
                [companyName] => Quikr
                [noOfDivision] => 10
                [companyAddress] => Manyatha Tech Park,Bangalore
                [companyStatus] => 0
            )
    )
)
```

> Table

```
<table id="demo-dt-basic" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>No of Division</th>
            <th >Company Address</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php
            $companyResponse = GetResponse(API_URL.'getCompanies');
        ?>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>TCS</td>
      <td>
         <button class="btn btn-success actionbtn"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</button>
         <button class="btn btn-danger actionbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DeleteModal"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</button>
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Company Id</td>
    <td>Company Name</td>
    <td>no Of Division</td>
    <td>Company Address</td>
    <td>Company Status</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
foreach ($companyResponse['data'] as $result) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $result['companyId']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['companyName']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['noOfDivision']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['companyAddress']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $result['companyStatus']; ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
```